# Android: Radio buttons not exclusive

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-radiogroup, android-radiobutton

I am trying to have a 2-by-2 layout of four radio buttons, with each button having an image with it. The problem is that the buttons are not exclusive, that is, I can select more than one Radio Button. Here's the xml code

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--<RadioGroup-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->
        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:onClick="image1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/hamburger96"
            android:layout_marginLeft="47dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="47dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"

            />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:onClick="image1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/trafficjam96"

            android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_marginTop="81dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:onClick="image1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/rockmusic96"



            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="35dp"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageButton3"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageButton3" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text=""
            android:onClick="image1"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton6"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/undercomputer96"

            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageButton5"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton4"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageButton4" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

I want something like this:[image]
How can I make it work?

Comment: Put them in a `RadioGroup`. `RadioGroup` is what gives the mutual-exclusion capability.

Comment: Uncomment the `RadioGroup` that you have and close the tag after the the last `RadioButton`.

Answer (score 2):

You should just need to place a `<RadioGroup>` tag before your first RadioButton and a closing `</RadioGroup>` tag after your last RadioButton.

The following works as desired from an Android assignment I had:

```
        <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="None" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Tip" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/radioButton3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Total" />
        </RadioGroup>
```